# Isolate scope directive and $observer in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm continuing my tragedy-journey trying to learn how to write good directives in AngularJS... but after reading many articles around I just have the same questions and problems.
Here is my test directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/rjR8Q2TQi59TWSW0emmo?p=preview

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">

    <span my-directive caption="{{foo}}"></span>

    <span my-directive caption="{{bar}}"></span>

  </body>

</html>
```

js:

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.foo = "initial foo";

  setTimeout(function() { // <-- simulate an async call or whatever...
    console.log('after 3 sec in foo:');
    $scope.foo = "changed foo";
  }, 3000);

  $scope.bar = "initial bar";

  setTimeout(function() { // <-- simulate an async call or whatever...
    console.log('after 3 sec in bar:');
    $scope.bar = "changed bar";
  }, 3000);

}]);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            caption: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('caption', function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

My questions are:

1) Why it doesn't get the update caption value after the delay?

2) Is there a better way to get the values updated without using $observe? (I read here: https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/effective-strategies-avoiding-watches-angularjs/ but none of the explained methods seems clean they just seems hacky-workarounds).

3) Is there any performance difference between $watch and $observe? (which is better? I've read everywhere to use $watch as less as I can, is the same for $observe).

Thank you to anyone that will make me clear all these stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. and 2. Use the `$timeout` service. `setTimeout` does not inform Angular about the changes it makes. You'd have to manually trigger a `$digest` cycle in the callback, which `$timeout` handles for you.

For more info, see [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout).

3. In general, `$watch` and `$observe` are the same, performance-wise. They are an indication that your code can be improved. As a rule of thumb, once you get around 2000 watchers on a page, it tends to get sluggish.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know it!